# Auto-filling a column with data once one cell has been updated

Tags: vba, excel

How can I auto-fill a column with 0's once one cell in the column has been filled?

Example:

Original Table

[image: Original Table]

Once I enter a number into any cell in the April Column...
[image]

I want the column to auto-fill the rest of the cells with 0's, like this...
[image]

My first idea was to use the Worksheet_Change event like so...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Set KeyCells = Range("H6:H16") 'H6 to H16 is the range of the April column, I would repeat this for each column in a loop

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Range("H6:H16").Value = 0 
End If
End Sub
```

But this overwrites the entire column, while I want to keep the original value.

Is there some way for Excel to return exactly what cell was changed so that I can change the value of all cells in that column except for that one? Or is there another easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Apr in H6:H16, your data range would seem to be in E6:P16.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6:P16")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim tgt As Range, var As Variant
        For Each tgt In Intersect(Target, Range("E6:P16"))
            With Cells(6, tgt.Column).Resize(11, 1)
                If Application.Count(.Cells) = 1 Then
                    var = tgt.Value
                    .Cells = 0
                    tgt = var
                End If
            End With
        Next tgt
    End If
bm_Safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Always disable event handling before writing values to the worksheet or you will trigger another [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro that runs on top of the original possibly triggering a cascade of events.

Answer (score 4):

Just thinking outside the box for a possible non-vba way of going about doing this.  You could first fill all the cells with zeros:

[image]

Then starting at A2, highlight the range "A2:L12" and go to **Home-->Conditional Formatting-->New Rule-->Use a formula to determine which cells to format** and insert the formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A$12,">0")=0
```

[image]

Then go to **Format-->Font** and change the font color to white (Another alternative, and probably a better one, would be to change the Number Format to Custom with a Type of `;;;` as suggested by Jeeped).

[image]

After you press OK a few times and have exited the conditional formatting rules manager, your sheet should look like this:

[image]

Once you add a value greater than zero to a cell, you will see all the zeros in the column appear.

[image]

This approach may not be acceptable for what you are trying to do since the value you enter has to be greater than zero, but I thought I would post it in case it is something you feel you can use.

Comment: When using similar methods,I've found that changing the Number Format to Custom with a Type: of `;;;` seems a little more invisible that a white font.

Comment: Nice! I like your formatting option better.  I made an edit to my answer

Comment: While this would work, it won't work for what I am doing. 

I have graphs that are based off of the data in the cells, so even though the user can't see the Zeroes, the charts would still be able to, and it would mess with the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Heres is my answer, hoping to give some help.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r
    Dim c
    Dim keyCells As Range
    Dim i

    r = Target.Row
    c = Target.Column
    'January in column E = 5
    'December in column P = 16
    Set keyCells = Range(Cells(6, c), Cells(16, c))

    If c >= 5 And c <= 16 Then ' if target is between the columns
        If r >= 6 And r <= 16 Then ' if the target is between the rows
            For Each i In keyCells
                If Not i.Address = Target.Address Then
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    i.Value = 0
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```